# GCP - gcloud login to service account using OAuth Token

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to export `OAuth access token` from service account like

`gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

and then log into this service account on another machine? I would like to be able to run `gcloud` commands using imported `OAuth access token`. So far I found it to be only possible when I am in possession of whole `json` file with auth data.

is it possible to be done?

Comment: I don't understand your question, that gcloud command will return an access token, I believe you can use that command to generate one for a service account by signing in with a service account. You could then use that one on another machine for as long as it is valid (1 hour I think). If you mean generate a refresh token (or longer duration access token), no that is not possible, why can you not just share the private key (which is the relevant part in the json)?

Comment: My scenario is: get access token from VM1, copy it to VM2 somehow import it to gcloud so I can use gcloud using service account from VM1

Comment: Does the VMs are compute engine, or another VM (on prem or on other cloud provider)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere its GCE but I am unable to use SA on VM2, only option is to use access token. It is ok for example for terraform but having access token I am unable to use gcloud command

Comment: If you are on compute engine, you don't need a service account key file. Firstly because a key file is a bad practice, especially on Google Cloud environment. Secondly, because it should work out of the box on GCE. Let fix your GCE issue, instead of looking for bad workaround ;) So, why are you not able to use SA on VM2?

Comment: I have gitlab-runner that is shared runner for more then 10 different projects. This runner use service account without any permissions. Whenever any projects run a pipeline it call `Hashicorp Vault` to get service account token for authorized account and once it is provided it setup `GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN` variable. It works great for terraform but I cannot execute gcloud command on behalf of service account I get access token @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Are the gitlab runner in a GKE cluster? Or raw on the VM?

Comment: Try adding the appropriate roles such as [service account token creator role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#token-creator-role) and other relevant IAM roles to the service account.

Comment: Importing an OAuth Token into the CLI is not supported.